# How do I produce a JSON document from PostgreSQL 1:n tables?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

I have the table "client" with:

```
id  name     registered_on  status
--  -------  -------------  ------
 1  Alice    2020-03-04     a     
 2  Vincent  2020-03-05     p     
 3  Anne     2020-03-06     a
```

And the table "account" with:

```
client_id  account_number  type  balance
---------  --------------  ----  -------
        1  300-1           CHK       100
        2  307-5           SAV        24
        2  307-6           CHK       350
```

I created them in [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vi9gDSxwfSbo7nnLC1mbk4/0).

Now, I need a SQL query to produce the 1:n JSON document.

There's a 1:n relationship between the tables and some clients may not have an account (such as "Anne"):

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Alice",
    "registered_on":"2020-03-04",
    "status":"a",
    accounts: [ 
      {
        "account_number": "300-1",
        "type": "CHK",
        "balance": 100.00
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Vincent",
    "registered_on":"2020-03-05",
    "status":"p",
    accounts: [ 
      {
        "account_number": "307-5",
        "type": "SAV",
        "balance": 24
      },
      {
        "account_number": "307-6",
        "type": "CHK",
        "balance": 350
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "name":"Anne",
    "registered_on":"2020-03-06",
    "status":"a",
    accounts: [ ]
  }  
]
```

The result is a simple join (probably an outer join) that I know how to do. I just don't get how to produce a JSON document from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the column `id` of the `client` table is a primary key. The key functions to use are [`to_jsonb()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) and [`jsonb_agg().`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select jsonb_pretty(jsonb_agg(r))
from (
    select
        to_jsonb(c) || jsonb_build_object(
            'accounts', 
            coalesce(nullif(jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(a)- 'client_id'), '[null]'), '[]')
            ) as r
    from client c
    left join account a on client_id = id
    group by c.id
    ) s
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=caecd0d638d2d788bdc01b169c06c49b)

Comment: There's one small detail I just found about this. In the third case "Anne" the JSON object should include an empty array of accounts, but ends up having an array of size 1 with an "null" value inside. Not a major issue, but wanted to document it, at least. Thanks again.